# What happened to Cloud City after Lando Calrissian's departure?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, return-of-the-jedi

Was Lando technically still in charge of Cloud City even though it certainly seems like he abandoned all of it for good and put all his stock, so to speak, in the Rebel Alliance?

Answer (score 7):

It seems after the death of Palpatine and Lando's departure the following occurred:

> In the absence of a baron administrator, a council of business representatives came to run the city
>   <sub>[Wookieepedia: Cloud City](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cloud_City)</sub>

Although I'd love to quote anything else. The [canon game](https://www.starwars.com/games-apps/star-wars-uprising) this is referenced from had its servers shut in November 2016.<sup>1</sup>

It goes on to say:

> Before word of the Emperor's death could reach the city, Imperial Governor Adelhard established the Iron Blockade over the entirety of the Anoat sector, shutting down travel and communications in and out of Cloud City. The city would also serve as the location of Governor Adelhard's personal chamber located within the prime tower. Ultimately, a militia led by Lobot would succeed in relaying messages to the New Republic, and with the aid of the [Uprising](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Uprising), would successfully liberate the city from Imperial control.

---

<sup>1</sup>  [Star Wars: Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Uprising)

Comment: Searching for the game's name and the word APK will lead you to unlicensed copies. But that would be [wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNXXpTsd_Co). Wrong and unethical. And naughty.

Comment: Well my phone also doesn't allow access to download APKs so I can't help here, sorry

Comment: [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/how-can-i-install-an-app-given-only-its-apk-file).

Comment: @Valorum I'm fully aware of the capability of android phones to install APKs, however AFAIK iPhones cannot. [Unless Jailbroken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335874/is-it-possible-to-run-apk-android-apps-on-ipad-iphone-devices)

Comment: Serves you right for owning a failphone :-P

Comment: [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator).

Comment: @Valorum ¯\_(ツ)_/¯